# ManifestChildren throwing InvalidArgumentException in Forge PHP SDK

Tags: autodesk-forge

My file is not being translated due to an exception:

```
Invalid value for 'role', must be one of '2d', '3d', 'graphics', 'manifest', 'thumbnail','Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase','viewable', 'ifc'
```

I debugged the SDK and the role that is causing the exception is `Autodesk.AEC.ModelData`.

> The file that I am trying to translate is the same I am used to translate in my application, so I think it is a problem in Forge PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is most likely an issue with the PHP SDK for Forge being out-of-date. I see that you already submitted a PR to the codebase - I will contact the dev team to make sure the new role type is recognized properly.

Comment: Thank you, I tested the translation with the new role and worked fine.